# Linux commandline (outputting text pattern from files)

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to output the line containing a certain pattern located in specifically named files in a unstructured directory hirearchy.  Each file I'm interested in is named "foo.xml".  The pattern I'm interested looks like: `<digit><digit>T<digit><digit>`  (as a PERL regex: `\d\dT\d\d`).  I want to output the entire line that matches this pattern (even the extra stuff on that line that doesn't match the pattern).

Where I'm at:

`find . | grep foo.xml` executed in the "root" gives me a list of the files I'd want to scan.

What do I do from here?

I'd much rather do this at the commandline.  I could easily write a PERL script but there's probably a really straight forward way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
find . -name foo.xml -exec grep REGEX '{}' \;
```

**edit** 
In your case the REGEX is

```
'[0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: so the -exec option to find executes any subsequent expressions, where '{}' is replaced by any found matches to the find command, and the command to execute is terminated by '\;'.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since you mentioned PERL, you can use grep's -perl-regexp option:

```
find . -name foo.xml -exec grep -P '\d\dT\d\d' '{}' \;
```

Lovely feature if you are used to perl regexes.